# SQL Server Conditional Joins

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, outer-join

I've three tables `Table1` `Table2` `Table3`. I've to perform some operations on them and store the resultant in `Table4`

**Table1:**

```````
ID       t1col2     t1col3  
``````   ``````     ``````
123      Fname1     Lname1
456      Fname2     Lname2  
789      Fname3     LnameAA
```````

**Table2:**

```````
ID        t2col2     t2col3     t2col4
`````     ``````     ``````     ``````
122       Fname1     Lname1     String1
466       Fname2     Lname2     String2
789       Fname3     Lname3     String3
```````

**Table3:**

```````
ID       t3col2       
``````   ``````      
122      querty     
789      asdfgh
```````

How can I perform conditional joins to check for following conditions:

- Search for a substring AA in `t1col3`.
- If found, replace `t1col3` value from **Table1** with `t2col3` value from **Table2** only when **Table1** `ID` 
  and **Table2** `ID` are equal.
- From the above result, search for matching `ID` in **Table3**
- If found, display the content in **Table4** as mentioned below.

**Expected output:**

**Table4:**

````````
ID         t1col2     t2col3     t2col4     t3col2  
```````    ```````    ```````    ```````    ```````  
789        Fname3     Lname3     String3    asdfgh
````````

Comment: Unless I missing something this sounds like a run of the mill everyday inner join to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First insert them in Table4.

Then correct Table1 based on Table4.

```
DELETE FROM Table4;

INSERT INTO Table4 (ID, t1col2, t2col3, t2col4, t3col2)
SELECT t2.ID, t1.t1col2, t2.t2col3, t2.t2col4, t3.t3col2
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.t1col3 LIKE '%AA%'
JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.ID = t1.ID;

UPDATE t1
SET t1col3 = t4.t2col3
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table4 t4 ON t4.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t1.t1col3 != t4.t2col3;

SELECT * 
FROM Table4 
ORDER BY ID;
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3976c6082fcd09775ae335ed38e71584)*

Result:

```
ID      t1col2      t2col3      t2col4      t3col2
----    --------    --------    --------    --------
789     Fname3      Lname3      String3     asdfgh
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try this

```
SELECT T1.ID , T1COL2, T2COL3, T2COL4, T3COL2
FROM TABLE2 AS T2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS T1 
  ON T2.ID = T1.ID AND T1.T1COL3 LIKE '%AA' 
INNER JOIN TABLE3 AS T3
  ON T3.ID = T2.ID
```

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6d9b5a8cff65b0b709498772ae979512)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Table1.ID, Table1.T1col2, Table2.T2col3, Table2.T2col4, Table3.T3col2
From Table1
Inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID AND Table1. t1col3 like ‘%AA%’ 
Inner join Table3 on Table1.ID = Table3.ID
```

Sorry but i didn’t understand what you want by : «  If found, replace t1col3 value from Table1 with t2col3 value from Table2 only when Table1 ID and Table2 ID are equal. » 
You want update value on table1 ?